# eclipse RCP : why tool bar is right aligned if its id is not "main"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application.
When I initialize the coolbar elements in method `fillCoolBar(final ICoolBarManager coolBar)`. If the id of ToolBarContributionItem is "main", then it displayed left aligned, else it displayed right aligned. 
I'm confused with this situation, could anyone tell me the reason, and how could I make it all left aligned?

```java
void fillCoolBar(final ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
    IToolBarManager tbm= new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
    coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(tbm, "main"));

    tbm.add(actionNew);
    tbm.add(actionOpen);
    tbm.add(actionSave);
}
```

when use above code, the items(actionNew, actionOpen, actionSave) are left aligned, if I change the id "main" to "main1", all those items are right aligned.

Comment: What is `toolBarManager`, the manager you created is `tbm`?

Comment: Also this isn't 'e4' which does not use the action bar advisor.

Comment: yes, it is the tbm, i have edited it. thank you.